# Include a main fxml with few controllers to other fxml layouts

Tags: javafx, include, fxml

Im doing a fxml project using netbeans 8.0.2 and scene builder 2.0 where I use FX8. What I want to do is add the home button, logout button power button and background css containing fxml which is the main fxml to all other fxml layouts so that the main is displayed and on top of that the sub fxml is displayed. (just like include property in php). Im using anchor panes to hold the controllers in the fxml. Ive came across with few methods by googling but none of them works.

```
<children>
<fx:include source="home.fxml"/>
</children>
```

was the 1st code I got which I included in the main.fxml page. Didnt work.

```
 <bottom>
<fx:include source="home.fxml"/>
</bottom>
```

this did not work and gave an error saying anchorpane doesnt support bottom tag.
It will be a great help if somebody can point me out where Ive missed. Thank you.

Comment: The 1st option should work. How did you determine that it didn't work?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I have been typing the code after the anchorpane tag which is not right. It should come inside the anchorpane tag.